# PAB requesting CONFIG_FILE on CLI

Tags: plutus

Trying to run `PAB` by executing:

`cabal exec -- myapp-pab webserver`

returns the following error:

`[Error] The --config option is required`

However, the lecture by Prof. Lars (PPP Lecture 6) didn't make mention of any config files.

What am I missing?

Comment: Aoaddeola.. thank you for sharing your knowledge with knowledge seekers. You are golden! I am just learning Haskell.. next Plutus. Have some minimal programming experience but very technical mind. Would love some suggestions for self education on the above mentioned languages. Thank you kindly!

Comment: @StephenSmith, you can learn Haskell [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/introduction) and Plutus [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zr3W8cgzIQ&list=PLK8ah7DzglhgV7W6BHcoIzRArjzs_UuSY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be in the right commit if you use the PAB as described in lecture 6 of the ppp, otherwise you will face problems. PAB and some other stuff changed.
I assume you build the project with `cabal build` without errors, try to `cabal run NAME_OF_EXECUTABLE`, e.g. `cabal run oracle-pab`. You don't need config files.
If you want a more up to date example use the Uniswap example form lecture 10, the implementation is still working with the latest plutus.

https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/tree/main/code/week10